# accessing UIAutomationCore.dll using JNA

Tags: java, dll, com, jna

I am extremely new to JNA and am kind of lost. I want to use the "**GetRootElement**" method present in the **IUIAutomation interface** inside the **UIAutomationCore.dll** in my java program.

Could someone please help me with some tutorial or code for the same?

Much appreciated.

UPDATE :

I tried doing something with the links provided by Daniel and now I face some other trouble. ***Class not registered***. Here is my code :

test.java

```
public class test {

public interface UIAutomationCore extends Library{
    UIAutomationCore INSTANCE = (UIAutomationCore) Native.loadLibrary("UIAutomationCore", UIAutomationCore.class);

    IUIAutomationElement GetRootElement();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     othermethod();
     //System.out.println(a.toString());
 }
 public static void othermethod(){
     IUIAutomation a = FactorySecond.createCUIAutomation();
     System.out.println(a.toString());
 }
}
```

FactorySecond.java

```
public abstract class FactorySecond {
 private FactorySecond() {}

 public static net.java.dev.jna.jna.IUIAutomation createCUIAutomation() {

  Factory factory = new Factory();
  return factory.createObject(net.java.dev.jna.jna.IUIAutomation.class);
 }
}
```

IUIAutomation.java

```
@ComObject(clsId="{30CBE57D-D9D0-452A-AB13-7AC5AC4825EE}")
public interface IUIAutomation extends IUnknown {
 @VTID(5)
    net.java.dev.jna.jna.IUIAutomationElement getRootElement();
}
```

It gives the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Class not registered (puArgErr=)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMUtils.checkRC(COMUtils.java:112)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMUtils.checkRC(COMUtils.java:95)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.Factory.createObject(Factory.java:151)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.FactorySecond.createCUIAutomation(FactorySecond.java:11)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.test.othermethod(test.java:21)
at net.java.dev.jna.jna.test.main(test.java:17)
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Not really answering your direct question, but I have written a library (https://github.com/mmarquee/ui-automation) that wraps the uiautomationcore.dll calls  into Java, via jna. Feel free to look at how I've wrapped the COM calls. Suggestions, tests, etc are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tutorial is the [Getting Started](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) link at the JNA project site.

You'll be doing something similar, loading the native library (UIAutomationCore) and then writing the function declaration for GetRootElement as a Java method, mapping the JNA types to Java types.

Check out [other Win32 library implementations](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I managed to do some play around with it and have ended up in some other com exception. Could you possibly help me and tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `IUIAutomationElement` defined?

Comment: Also you've significantly changed the scope of your question from the original.  In cases like this it's better to ask an entirely new question... most people will see that this one is answered and skip by it; you're stuck with (probably) only me reading this now...

Comment: How did you choose 5 for the VTID?

Comment: Apologies. I will create a new question on this right now.
And, the IUIAutomationElement is defined as :

@ComInterface(iid="{D22108AA-8AC5-49A5-837B-37BBB3D7591E}")
public interface IUIAutomationElement extends IUnknown {
 }

Since its just an interface which should be taken from the above mentioned IID.

And for the VTID, I checked in oleview the index of the GetRootElement method in IUIAutomation interface and it was 5. So..

Comment: Hope you get help on your new question. It's beyond the scope of what I know now :)